# XPath call from iOS not working right

Tags: ios, xml, xpath, gdataxml

I have the following data

```
<Table>
<Row>
    <Cell><Data>Row Labels</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>Searches</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>Purchases</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>CRatio</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>AvgReturn</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>Commission</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Cell><Data>2013</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>2257224</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>18574</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>8.2286915255198427E-3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>43.459007223015384</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>102390.82995242</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Cell><Data>2014</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>5351610</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>43035</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>8.0415052666393851E-3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>40.420168915503282</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>280677.31032664998</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Cell><Data>Grand Total</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>7608834</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>61609</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>8.0970356299007173E-3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>41.336323742293686</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data>383068.14027907007</Data></Cell>
</Row>
```

Whats the best way using XPath to get one  of data at a time of data and then to get at indiviual  elements in that

I have tried the following ...

```
enter  NSArray *rowNodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"/Table/Row" error:&error];

BOOL doBreak = NO;
@try {


    int iRow = 0;
    for (GDataXMLElement *rowNode in rowNodes) {
        iRow++;

        //get cell elements of the row

        NSArray* rowCellNodes = [rowNode nodesForXPath:@"//Cell/Data" error:&error];
```

However when I do this I get the rowNodes correctly, but then I get no results for rowCellNodes in the for loop.

Comment: try to add a dot at the beginning of the 2nd XPath : `.//Cell/Data` ?

Comment: you genius! that worked. thank you sir!

Comment: You are welcome. Converted my comment to answer so that future visitors can spot the solution easier.

Comment: Yes was going to suggest you do that so I can accept it formally - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a dot at the beginning of the 2nd XPath to make it recognized as relative XPath to current `rowNode` :

```
NSArray* rowCellNodes = [rowNode nodesForXPath:@".//Cell/Data" error:&error];
```